# How do I reverse easylist numbering?

Tags: easylist

I would like [easylist](/questions/tagged/easylist) to count down from `n` at the top and 1 at the bottom. I searched through the manual, but couldn't find if there was a way to do that.

Comment: I fear that this is only possible with hacking deeply into this (already quite dated) package ... Maybe you can look at the `markdown` package which allows you to use markdown sytax (which is similarly easy to that used by `easylist`) and then look at the `enumitem` package to reverse the counter ... there is one example in the `enumitem` package on that as far as I know.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Since no other answers have come in, i'd consider that as a response

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear whether `easylist` can be hacked to do reverse numbering, but if you want that functionality with a regular looking list syntax, the `etaremune` package can do what you want.  This is a less resource intensive package than the `revnum` package, which "uses 4 counters plus 1 for every `revnumerate` environment in the document" (p.1 of the `etaremune` documentation).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etaremune}
\begin{document}
\begin{etaremune}
\item This is the first item.
\item This is the second item.
\item This is the third item.
\item This is the fourth item.
\end{etaremune}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to persuade `easylist`, you could instead use one of the packages specifically designed to do reverse enumeration.

One example with the [revnum package](https://ctan.org/pkg/revnum):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{revnum}

\begin{document}

\begin{revnumerate}
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{revnumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]